# how to reduce dependency in running QTP without having it installed?

Tags: qtp

how to reduce dependency in running QTP without having it installed?

Comment: What do you mean? That's like saying "how do I run MS Word without having it installed..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definetely need to install QTP to run it.

Even if you just want to use it through its automation interface, or as an agent-driven test robot for a LoadRunner scenario.

And also even if you just want to execute QTP tests from a QualityCenter test set.
That's one of the big drawbacks of QTP -- it is a very fat application. There is no way to avoid having to install the full IDE.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't run QTP without having it installed.